# How to return linked list from a function?

Tags: c, linked-list

Firstly, sorry for my bad english, hope you understand me.
I'm new into programming in general and need help in a small project our teacher asked us to do. (Homework.)
In this homework I created a linked list:

```
struct No {
    char Nome[30];
    char Endereco[30];
    int Numero;
    int aux;
    struct No *prox;
};
typedef struct No no;
```

Then, I added functions to populate an array. The problem is just that one of my function isn't changing the array in any way, its like if I'm not calling the function at all.
Here are the important parts:

```
int main(void)
{
    no *lista = (no *) malloc(sizeof(no)); //This is the linked list I'm talking about.

    Contagem=0;

    int iOpcao;
    while(iOpcao) {
        iOpcao=Escolha();
        if(selecionarOpcao(lista,iOpcao) == 0)
            return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int selecionarOpcao(no *entrada, int op)
{
    no *tmp;
    switch(op){
        case 0:
            return 0;

        case 1:
            ListarContatos(entrada);
            break;

        case 2:
            AdicionarContato(entrada);
            break;

        case 3:
            RemoverContato(entrada);
            break;

        case 4:
            EditarContato(entrada);
            break;

        case 5:
            entrada = OrganizarLista(entrada); //This is the function not working correctly, the other ones are working perfectly fine.
            break;

        default:
            printf("Comando invalido\n\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And finally the function itself:

```
no* OrganizarLista(no* entrada) {
    no* ordenada = (no *) malloc(sizeof(no));
    no* temp = entrada;
    no* maiorNo = NULL;

    while(1 == 1) {
        while(temp != NULL) {
            temp = temp->prox;
            if(temp != NULL) {
                if(JaExistente(ordenada, temp->Numero) == 1)
                    continue;

                if(temp->prox != NULL && maiorNo == NULL) {
                    if(JaExistente(ordenada, temp->prox->Numero) == 1) {
                        maiorNo = temp;
                        continue;
                    }

                    //printf("%s contra %s", temp->Nome, temp->prox->Nome);
                    if(maiorNo == NULL)
                        maiorNo = CompararNos(temp, temp->prox);

                    //printf("%s ganhou.\n", maiorNo->Nome);
                }
                else if(maiorNo != NULL) {
                    //printf("%s contra %s", maiorNo, temp->Nome);
                    maiorNo = CompararNos(maiorNo, temp);
                    //printf("%s ganhou.\n", maiorNo->Nome);
                }
            }
        }

        if(maiorNo != NULL) {
            //printf("Maiorno->nome = %s", maiorNo->Nome);
            AdicionarLista(ordenada, maiorNo->Nome, maiorNo->Endereco, maiorNo->Numero, 1);
            temp = entrada;
            maiorNo = NULL;
        }
        else {
            temp = entrada;
            while(temp != NULL) {
                if(JaExistente(ordenada, temp->Numero) == 0)
                    AdicionarLista(ordenada, temp->Nome, temp->Endereco, temp->Numero, 1);
                temp = temp->prox;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    free(temp);

    return ordenada;
}
```

I spent the whole day trying to figure it out however it is still not working. When I check the values inside the function they are all correct but when the values are returned it seems like the program just ignore them.
Any help is appreciated, again, sorry for my english and thanks everyone!

Comment: Return a pointer to the first element.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not specific, the thing is, anything I return from that function makes no change to the actual list. sry.

Comment: Don't ever cast the return value of `malloc`

Comment: Sorry, I was only reacting to the title. The code barely matches the title.

Comment: If you can add JaExistente(), and CompararNos() functions code or add comment what you are trying to do with it then it will be easier to solve your problem.

Comment: JaExistente() function only checks if a value already exists in that list and CompararNos() is a function I made for checking which name should be used in the new generated list. They are working fine and their code is quite big, I simply don't want to bother anyone more than I'm already doing.

Comment: I printed the values of the ordenada array before it gets returned, they are 3 0 3. However, printing the same array when it is was already returned shows as 1 0 2, the starting value.

Comment: Note that you're using an uninitialized variable in `main()` at `int iOpcao;
    while(iOpcao) {` so anything can happen.  There's no guarantee the loop will be entered — there's no guarantee it won't be entered either.  You need to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answer and comments, I am just feeling I'm not familiar enough with C right now so I will do that homework in another programming language I'm more familiar with. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to set a new value for parameter that was sent by value.
In order to send a pointer or any variable to a function and let the function change its value, you should send it by reference, its address.

Assumimg you have the following functions:

```
void changePtr(no **ptr) {
    *ptr = // .. some value
}
void dontChangePtr(no *ptr) {
    ptr = // some value
}
```

You should notice the differences between the function calls:

```
no *n = (no*)malloc(sizeof(no));
dontChangePtr(n); // n will be sent by value and will not be changed
changePtr(&n); // n will be sent by reference and will be changed
```

Comment: C does not support pass-by-reference! A pointer is a first-class type!

Comment: I made a simple test based on your answer, changing my function OrganizarLista to OrganizarLista(no** entrada) { *entrada = NULL } and the results were the same, the list on the function calling it still didn't change.
Let me give you an example: My list is 1, 2 and 3. I call the test function above and the list continues as 1, 2 and 3. Thanks for the help.